# Why is $\inf g \sup g = \frac{9}{16} $?

Tags: calculus, geometry, fractions, limsup-and-liminf, products

Consider this question here :

[Why is $\sup f_- (n) \inf f_+ (m) = \frac{5}{4} $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2075374/why-is-sup-f-n-inf-f-m-frac54)

Call that conjecture about $\frac{5}{4} $ conjecture $1$.

Let $g(n) = \prod_{i=0}^n (\sin^2(n) + \frac{9}{16}) ) $

Conjecture $3$ :

——-

Conjecture $2$ is :

$$ \sup g(n) \space \inf g(n) = \frac{9}{16} $$

And this follows from conjecture $1$ or vice versa.

——-

It feels like this second conjecture could somehow follow from the first conjecture since

$$-(\cos(n) + \frac{5}{4})(\cos(n) - \frac{5}{4}) = - \cos^2(n) + \frac{25}{16} = \sin^2(n) + \frac{9}{16} $$

This question is about the connection ( conjecture $3$).

If you can prove conjecture $1$ or $2$ post it in the other thread.

Btw $ \int_0^{2 \pi} \ln(\sin^2(x) + \frac{9}{16}) dx = 0 $ indeed as you probably already knew or guessed.

Comment: Now posted also on MathOverflow: [Why is $\sup f_- (n) \inf f_+ (m) = \frac{5}{4} $?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/322240)