# About $ f(w,L) = \int_1^w \int_0^{2 L \pi} \frac{ \ln(\frac{\sin(x) +\ sin(vx)}{2} + \frac{5}{4})}{L(w - 1)} dx dv $

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing, trigonometric-integrals

Consider

$$ f(w,L) = \int_1^w \int_0^{2 L \pi} \frac{ \ln(\frac{sin(x) + sin(vx)}{2} + \frac{5}{4})}{L(w - 1)} dx dv $$

For real $w > 1 $ and integer $ L > 1$

Conjecture :

$$ \lim_{L \to \infty} f(w + 1, L) - f(w,L) = 0. $$

How to decide if this is true ?

Perhaps differentiation under the integral sign is the best method ?

——

To see where “ this is coming from “ ,

Notice

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \ln(sin(x) + \frac{5}{4}) dx = 0 $$

And look at these :

[Why is $\sup f_- (n) \inf f_+ (m) = \frac{5}{4} $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2075374/why-is-sup-f-n-inf-f-m-frac54)

[Why is $\inf g \sup g = \frac{9}{16} $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3000441/why-is-inf-g-sup-g-frac916)

—-

Comment: Although the Integral looks complicated it might be expressible in special functions ? I was thinking about hypergeometric. If that would be simpler or even helpful is another matter ...

Comment: I think the conjecture is false actually but hard to show false ?